# Resize a byte array

Tags: c++, android, java-native-interface

In a native function with a jbyteArray argument, I want to pass data back into the calling app using SetByteArrayRegion.

I would like to resize the array to exactly fit the data, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Arrays are fixed size in java.

Possible solution would be to use a different data structure (e.g. ArrayList) or you could create a jbyteArray of the correct size and let the native function return this.

Comment: Ok, too bad, I need the return argument to indicate results. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible, just as you can't resize arrays in java.

You need to create and return new array.